# how to return multiple records from single record in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have source Tbl like

```
CID   No_Of_Seats_Booked  Seat_Numbers
-------------------------------------
1            3              01A01B01C
```

Tgt table O/P

```
CID Seat_id
------------
1    01A    
1    01B    
1    01C
```

Comment: Try building your database a way you don't save multiple data in 1 column. Here i.e., you can create another table "booking_seat" with columns Booking_id, seat_id and a table seats with all available seats seat_id and seat_number. That way, saving the number is obsolete, you can change your seats names and all older bookings still work and you dont get the names mixed up. "normalize" is the key player here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (cid, no_of_seats_booked, seat_numbers) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 1, 3, '01A01B01C' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 2, '02A02B'    from dual)
  5  -- query you need begins here
  6  select cid,
  7         substr(seat_numbers, 1 + (column_value - 1) * 3, 3) seat_id
  8  from test cross join
  9    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                        connect by level <= no_of_seats_booked
 11                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12  order by cid, seat_id;

       CID SEA
---------- ---
         1 01A
         1 01B
         1 01C
         2 02A
         2 02B

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, just for variety:

```
with demo(cid, no_of_seats_booked, seat_numbers) as
     ( select 1, 3, '01A01B01C' from dual union all
       select 2, 2, '02A02B' from dual
     )
select d.cid
     , regexp_substr(d.seat_numbers, '...', 1, r.rnum) seat_id
from   demo d
       cross apply (select rownum as rnum from dual connect by rownum <= d.no_of_seats_booked) r
order  by d.cid, seat_id;
```